# Dell XPS 15 blue screens only while running on battery

Tags: laptop, bsod, battery, fan

I have a weird issue which I can't seem to work out. My Dell XPS 15 9550 with Windows 10 installed seems to randomly blue screen. I've been trying to isolate why it is happening and doesn't seem to be when I use the keyboard, touchpad or anything like that. One thing I have worked out is this **only happens** while the laptop is running from the battery, and works fine if it is plugged in running on mains power.

When it blue screens, it doesn't dump anything, it stays at 0% and doesn't log anything in the event logs. Once, when running Dell Diags, it reported a video fan failure, but not sure why this only happens on battery. I have tried:

1. Updating BIOS
2. Running Dell Diagnostics
3. Reseating the two fans inside the laptop
4. Updating all drivers
5. All Windows Updates

Attached are the two relevant photos. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Screenshot of [BSOD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHKNV.jpg)

Screenshot of [Dell Diag Reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8wTQ.jpg)

Comment: [How to Fix an Unexpected Store Exception Error in Windows 10](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/unexpected-store-exception-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a battery, battery-connector or PCB power trace failure, particularly since you show code 73787, battery "not installed".

To check the cause of the issue, the case would need to be opened.

- Is there a break in the copper conductors of the PCB board by the battery? On a multilayer board, a break may be hidden in the middle, but the most mechanical stress is on the outside layers, where a break can be seen with a magnifier.
- Are soldered connections complete? It might help to reflow those from the battery.
- Is the battery connector firmly seated?
- Does the battery seemed to be distorted?

There have been some [reports of battery swelling](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/Swelling-XPS-15-9550-batteries/td-p/5180839), so if you notice an obvious physical issue, e.g. case being expanded, remove the battery (or have it removed) and place it away from flammable material.

[Replacements are available for ~US$65](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075SSN2RY) to [$US80 for an OEM battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XRYJX2T). Before spending that much on a repair, have the battery checked under load, and with some mechanical prodding, to be sure it actually is defective.